# Rotating an array according to user input

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to rotate an array according to the user input, I want to take the array from the user and number of positions to shift from, from the user, and the direction to shift in i.e., left or right from the user(which can be taken as 0 for left and 1 for right) So far I could do this

```js
const numList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
const p = 3

function changeArray(arr, shift) {
  for (let i = 0; i < shift; i++) {
    arr.unshift(arr.pop())
    console.log(`${i+1}:`, arr)
  }
}

console.log(changeArray(numList, p))
```

I am doing this to take inputs from user:

```
const numList= prompt("Type your array")
const p=prompt("Type your position")
```

Please tell me how can I take the input from the user.

this gives me the expected output but I want to take the inputs from user and when I try that it says, `arr.pop()` is not a function. I also couldn't add the direction functionality to it, could anyone tell me what can be done here?

Comment: `console.log(arr);` and see what value you're passing in. It must not be an array if `.pop()` is not a function.

Comment: What does "take the inputs from the user" mean? Are you having trouble passing command line arguments to a node script? Please edit your question to include the code you're asking about, and please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking additional questions.

Comment: Can you please post the code on how you are getting the inputs from the user? The current code does not throw the error you have posted.

Comment: And the code that was giving `arr.pop` is not a function?

Comment: @Rajesh I have edit my question, please see now

Comment: @adiga  I have edit my question, please see now

Comment: @ashrth Prompt will give you a string. You will have to split it

Comment: @AndyRay I mean I want to take the array and the position to shift from, from the user instead of hardcoding it,

Comment: @Rajesh OK, Noted!

Comment: You can just change the array functions based on the direction like this: https://jsfiddle.net/m0wbLx8a/ or https://jsfiddle.net/bz5hxr9n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const n = prompt("Type your array").split(',');
const p = prompt("Amount to rotate by?");
const d = prompt("Direction? L/R").toUpperCase().includes('L') ? -1 : 1;
console.log(n.map((_,i,a)=>+a[(a.length+i-(p%a.length*d))%a.length]));
```

Comment: @ashrth btw there was a bug in an earlier version that I just fixed

Comment: @ashrth also I just tweaked it again to ensure that the array that is output contains numbers and not strings

Comment: Yes, I saw it, thanks again

Comment: can you also tell me the time and space complexity of your solution?

Comment: @ashrth it's O(n)

Comment: and space complexity is? Sorry for bothering you like this

Comment: @ashrth both are O(n)

Comment: Andrew Parks, can you answer this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74714225/19336351

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `array.slice`

Idea:

- `Array.slice` takes negative numbers which will return ending n numbers. You create a new list starting these numbers
- Call `Array.slice` again but from starting position (0) and use `length - n` to get remaining numbers

Also, its better to not mutate an same array that you are looping on. `pop` will change the length and so will `unshift`. It can have weird outcome. Using a new array is better and works with immutability concept as well

```js
const rotateArr = (arr, p, direction) => {
  if (direction === "left")
    return [
      ...arr.slice(-1 * p),
      ...arr.slice(0, arr.length - p)
    ]
  else
    return [
      ...arr.slice(p),
      ...arr.slice(0, p)
    ]
}


const data = prompt("Enter comma seperated values")
  .split(",")
  .map(Number)
const position = Number(prompt("Enter Position to shift"))
const direction = prompt("Enter the direction? Left or Right")

console.log(rotateArr(data, position, direction))
```

Comment: The code they have posted is already working. Their issue with getting the direction of rotation as a an argument and an error *"arr.pop() is not a function"* for which they have not shared the code.

Comment: @adiga Good point. Have updated the answer with `direction`. Cannot comment on error as OP's code does not reflect that

Comment: @rajesh thank you for your suggestion, could you please tell me what can be done to rotate this particular array in a particular direcction (direction - either 0 for left or 1 for right). The objective is to return the array shifted by p positions in d direction.

Comment: @adiga Now I have updates my code

Comment: @ashrth There is an `if` that is handling direction. For `0` or `1` values, you will have to update the condition only. I have also integrated prompts as well

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you so much, it solves half of my problem

Comment: @Rajesh thank you if is working fine, but I am not able to change the direction to right, when I try to do, it gives me the same output as Left